# How to analyze ranked data with multiple variables

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, classification, feature-engineering

I have data points with 10 variable values each, each belonging to one of two groups (A and B) that look like this:

Group A:

datap1 = [0.2,0.4,0.7,...,1.4] 
datap2 = [0.1,0.5,0.9,...,1.9] 
datap3 = [1.2,1.8,2.1,...,2.9] 
dataN = [dist1, dist2, dist3,...,dist10] etc.

Group B has similar data points, but the number of data points in group A and B are not same. They are 100 and 150 respectively.

These variables are distances and they go on increasing (ranked variables)

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to calculate a new variable that captures the information about the factor of ordering? So far there is no pattern, they are just distances.
2. Is there a way I can compare the two groups?  If they are different? Compare their distribution? Maybe I can use the variable created in question 1. 
   And if yes -
   I am hoping that once I get a new datapointX = [dist1, dist2, ..., dist10], I want to give probability of this data point belonging to one of these groups.